Как принять местоположения пользователя в aiogram3.x
@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    builder = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
    btn_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text=' Поделиться геолокацией', request_location=True)
    builder.row(btn_geo)

Вопрос - как принять геопозицию от пользователя? aiogram==3.6.0
Нашел ответы для 2.х но как в 3 не понимаю

@dp.message(F.location)
async def handle_location(message: types.location):
    print('callback', message.location)



пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
